# Same values for lm and tslm models

Tags: r, time-series, linear-regression, lm

I used lm () and tslm () in r for model fitting. When, I checked the summary. I got the same results for both models.
My data frame is time series from 2015-2021.

```
    library(fpp)
    library(forecast)
    ts_df = as.ts(df_new2)

    ts_model <- tslm(Life_expectancy ~ Age+Gender+Race, data=ts_df)
     summary(ts_model)

     #multiple regression
     model <- lm(Life_expectancy~Age+Race+Gender, data = df_new)

     summary(model)
```

Comment: From `?tslm` : "*tslm is largely a wrapper for lm() except that it allows variables "trend" and "season" which are created on the fly from the time series characteristics of the data*" .  Nothing wrong here.